Is there a way to slow down an SSD trim so it doesn't affect the drive's read performance while it is in progress?
On my test Linux box with a Transcend TS2TMTE662T2-G1 SSD installed. I created a 100GB dummy file on my 1.8TB ext4 partition, and then I ran cat <bigdummy.bin >/dev/null to sequentially read the data from that file as quickly as possible.
With cat running, I ran iostat -t nvme0n1p6 --human 1 in a different shell window to monitor what the SSD's read-performance was like... it looks pretty good, I'm reading in ~2.2 gigabytes per second:
Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
nvme0n1p6     18232.00         2.2G         0.0k         0.0k       2.2G       0.0k       0.0k

I then used rm to delete about 600GB of (unrelated) files from the partition, and then I ran fstrim --all to tell the SSD to start erasing the newly-discarded blocks.  While that trimming was going on, I looked at iostat's output again to see how my cat process's read-performance was now faring:
Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
nvme0n1p6       215.00        18.1M         0.0k         8.8G      18.1M       0.0k       8.8G

Ecch, not very good at all.  Read bandwidth has been reduced to a measly 18MB/sec, and the transactions-per-second is similarly down by a factor of 100.
It's probably unreasonable for me to expect 100% of normal read performance from an SSD that is also in the middle of doing 8.8G/s of kb_dscd's... but since the block-discarding operation isn't particularly time-critical (in that I don't care that much whether it completes in 30 seconds or continues for 30 minutes), is there any way for me to slow that process down so that my drive's read-performance won't be so badly impacted while it is going on?  e.g. if the SSD was only doing 500 M/s of kb_dscd operations, it would (perhaps) have more time left over to handle its normal read-I/O tasks at something approaching its usual rate?
(motivation:  this is for a media streaming box that will eventually want to do simultaneous recording and playback, potentially 24/7, and it would be really nice if I could periodically initiate TRIM operations without significantly impacting the box's ability to continue streaming content at the same time.)

Not an answer because it's an untested idea which may not work depending on what fstrim does internally, but have you tried ionice -c 3 fstrim ... ?

If you have exhausted all non zeroed space, how would slowing the zero process help given that it is required to use the cells?

@GregAskew the intent is to avoid exhausting the pool of zeroed pages by executing a trim operation before that occurs... but also to avoid having the trim operation itself introduce performance issues during the period in which it is executing.

I think the usage and design is forcing this situation. I can take any SSD and do that in a relatively short period of time. Fast, good, and cheap. Pick two.

Not a proper answer, but you might also try mounting the filesystem with the discard option instead of using fstrim. A lot of people recommend against this, but that’s mostly because it has nasty performance implications with SATA drives because of interactions between the TRIM command and command queueing for those drives. For NVMe it’s often ‘good enough’, and depending on your filesystem it may do a much better job than firing off a global fstrim.

Also, you may see significantly different behavior with a different NVMe drive. None of the ones I’ve seen had anywhere near that kind of performance hit for bulk discard operations, so it’s entirely possible that what you’re seeing is the real-world impact of poorly written firmware.

fstrim accepts -o (offset) and -l (length) options. You can use them to limit the amount of trimmed LBA per command invocation.

Interesting -- but how could I determine what values to pass in?

For starting, reasonable values can be between 8-64 MB. Anyway, if you can tolerate a nightly fstrim for the whole disk, I would not care about smaller trims.

@shodnshok the problem is that the machine may be doing streaming operations 24/7, in which case there isn't any time where it can tolerate a full-disk fstrim without the streaming being impacted.
